# Preprocessor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, preprocessor, template-haskell

I want to generate `import qualified Aaaa.Bbb.Ccc as Ccc` automatically at **compile** time.

Is there any way to do that? Maybe by Template Haskell or anyhow else with any extention? I think it's similar to macroses in C and the function `$(...)` in Tempalte Haskell.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have some import statement you want to change for different package versions?

Comment: Probably will be useful Conditional Compilation https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#conditional-compilation

Comment: You can enable the CPP preprocessor, as in C. Use `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` at the top of your file, and `#define` or `#include` your macros. Still, I wonder if that is really necessary.

Comment: TH cannot generate import statements, so you are stuck with the c preprocessor.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are trying to achieve is shortening your import list, you may try the following trick. Create a new module (`Foo`):

```
module Foo (module X) where
import A as X
import B as X
import C as X
```

Then import this module to get all members of `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
module Bar where
import qualified Foo as X
```

This way you can combine modules which are commonly used throughout your project.

If you still need to auto-generate the imports, at least you only need to generate module `Foo`, but not `Bar`. So the automatically and manually generated code is separated cleanly.